# Magento2 Blank Invoice, Shipping, Credit Memos

Tags: magento2

I'm completely stuck on this. When you view and order under Sales > Orders. Then click on the invoices tab it is completely empty. Same for credit memos and shipments. I can view them fine under their individual links such as Sales > Invoices. There seems to be no errors showing in console or in error logs. Anyone got any ideas?[image]

Comment: any error in the browser console?

Comment: Nope nothing at all

Comment: Check Magento log files <install_directory>/var/log/system.log and <install_directory>/var/log/exception.log
OR
Enable developer mode, uncomment #ini_set('display_errors', 1); in app/bootstrap.php and check blank page again.

Comment: yes its not throwing anything into error_log or the magento logs. Comparing to another site it seems to be missing the script bits <script type="text/x-magento-init">{"*": {"Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {"types":{"dataSource":[],"bookmark":{"extends":"sales_order_view_invoice_grid","current":{"search"......